# How to split file by line count and rename based on column value

Tags: awk, split

I have a file that needs to be split by every 4 lines. Each 4 lines look like:

```
sample_id   145 WORD    2847    42  301M    =   2086    -1062
ACAAAAAAGAAAAAATGAGTTACCGTACTGTCTGTGAGTGATGCATACTTTT
  |||||||||||||| ||| || ||||||  |||| |||||||||| ||||
TTAAAAAAGAAAAAATCAGTAACAGTACTGGATGTGGGTGATGCATATTTTT
```

so far I use

```
split -l 4 file.txt
```

I want to rename the output files so that it looks like `sample_id.txt` taken from the first column in the first line. How can I do this, is there an awk solution?

Comment: We can't test a script to split an input file every 4 lines if you only provide 4 lines of sample input. Please [edit] your question to show a sample input file of at least 8 lines and the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR % 4 != 1 { p = p ORS $0; next }
    function f() { if (length(p) && length(i)) print p > (i ".txt"); close(i ".txt") }
    { f(); p = $0; i = $1 }
    END { f() }' file
```

Comment: `print p > i ".txt"` will fail with a syntax error in some awks, it needs to be `print p > (i ".txt")` to work in all awks, You'll also run into a "too many open files" error in some awks while others will slow down noticeably once you get past some threshold due to not closing the output files as you go.

Comment: @EdMorton Right, a close is necessary. Which awk will cause syntax error?

Comment: Your script fails with `awk: syntax error at source line 2 in function f
 context is
     function f() { if (length(p) && length(i)) print p > i >>>  ".txt" <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 2 in function f` using awk version 20200816 on MacOS. idk which versions of other awks would fail similarly today or in future as not having parens around an expression on the right side of input or output redirection is undefined behavior so any implementer can do whatever they like with it.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok that's pretty fair. I added the enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want (untested due to inadequate sample input and no expected output):

```
awk '
    (NR%4) == 1 {
        if ( NR > 1 ) {
            printf "%s", rec > out
            close(out)
        }
        out = $1 ".txt"
        rec = ""
    }
    { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    END { printf "%s", rec > out }
' file.txt
```